# Determination of face width

Tags: gears

This is my first time posting here. I am tasked with using the AGMA (American Gear Manufacturers Association) standards/equations to back calculate the the face width of a of a gear connected to a ball mill.

Essentially I am calculating the required face width of the girth gear to see if it will hold up with a more powerful motor (700 kW from 590 kW). For reference the current face width of the gear is around 400 - 500 mm.

The only inputs to my calculation spreadsheet are:

Motor
-700 kW:
-8.05 kNm running torque
-14.53 kNm start torque
-674 rpm

The pinion has 19 teeth.

The gear (girth gear) has 232 teeth.

The pinion/gear pair is helical with a helix angle of 7 degrees and a pressure angle of 20 degrees. They have a module of 20 mm. The pinion has a face width of 400 mm. Assume that I already know the values for things like allowable contact stress etc.

There is a reduction gearbox between the motor and the pinion, which has a reduction ratio of 3.18:1

I've been stuck on this task for over a week now, and it must be done in 15 hours. Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Define your max load and max power situations. Compare to the strength of the teeth.

Comment: Thanks for the response MIke. What are the relevant equations? The equations from the AGMA standard that I was given to do the calcs don't have equations for max load. Also, what type of max load are we talking about, the tangential loads on the pinion/gear etc?